# Automate jquery ajax forms

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, forms

I want to automate a click function with the following piece of code so that the form votes are directly submitted. Is there any way to create a standalone script that submits the votes without having to refresh the webpage:

```
<input type="submit" id="edit-vote" name="op" value="Vote" class="form-submit" />  </div>
<input type="hidden" name="form_build_id" value="form-_uSQFCS2yhwHuEB3IMSjehiyfoonqUt9ExArzLqWrqo" />`</div>
```

This is the radio button I want to click:

```
<div class="form-item form-type-radio form-item-choice">
 <input type="radio" id="edit-choice-39328" name="choice" value="39328" class="form-radio" />  <label class="option" for="edit-choice-39328"> OPTION  </label>
```

Please suggest if more information is needed

Comment: Submit without refresh looks terribly like Ajax...

Comment: As @RaphaëlAlthaus suggested, check for `JQuery Ajax`.

Answer (score 0):

Add a class to your radio input then

```
$("input.your_class").change(function() {
  if ($(this).prop("checked")) {
    $("#your_form_element_id').submit();
  }
});
```

I assume you have a form element (wrapping your input[type=submit] and your input[type=hidden]) with the id 'your_form_element'.

Good luck

Comment: This will submit the form as well as refresh the page.

Comment: Can you please explain how to execute this code to get results in the webpage? Including the changes to be made in the code. I'm sorry, I'm only aware of Javascript. Thanks